# In Javascript does a recursive function release it's resources once it has hit the base case and starts moving back down the stack?

Tags: javascript

That is, should you care about returning objects inside of a recursive function if you don't even reference the object until the very bottom of the stack?

Comment: My guess would be that it depends on the JS engine.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript releases memory at some indeterminate point after your variables no longer point to it. If you return an object from the base, and then continue to return it, it should not be released, unlike a local variable C, for example.